# Getting object out of switch cases

Tags: java, switch-statement

I have a menu driven program where the user is prompted to input integers in order to create a BST.  Everything works great the first time around, but if the user goes back to the main menu and selects to create a new binary search tree, the new input is actually just added on to the old tree.  I know it is because I am creating my tree outside of the switch statement, however, if I create it inside of my first switch statement so that ever ytime a new tree is created, the other switch statements won't have access to the tree...any ideas on where I should actually be creating my tree?

```
package model;

import java.io.*; 
import java.util.*; 


public class menu {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int integerInput;
        int inputOption;
        int myCategoryChoice;

        InOrder inOrder;
        PreOrder preOrder;
        PostOrder postOrder;
        Context context;

        BinaryTree myIntTree;

        myIntTree = new BinaryTree();
        inOrder = new InOrder();
        preOrder = new PreOrder();
        postOrder = new PostOrder();

        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        do{
            System.out.println("=======================================");
            System.out.println("     Binary Search Tree Traversal!     ");
            System.out.println("=======================================");
            System.out.println("Options:                               ");
            System.out.println("  1.  Create a new binary search tree  ");
            System.out.println("  2.  Traverse the tree                ");
            System.out.println("  3.  Quit                             ");
            System.out.println("=======================================");

            inputOption = KeyIn.inInt("Please select an option from the menu: ");

            switch(inputOption){
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("You've selected to create a new binary tree." + "\n");
                    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
                    String tempInput;
                    Boolean repeat = true;
                    try{
                        System.out.println("Please enter as many integers as you'd like, hit 'Q' when you are finished." + "\n");
                        do{

                            tempInput = scan.next();
                            if(!tempInput.equals("Q") && !tempInput.equals("q")){
                                integerInput = Integer.parseInt(tempInput);
                                myIntTree.insert(integerInput);
                                repeat = true;
                            }
                            else
                                repeat = false;

                        }while(repeat);

                    }catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                            System.out.println("Invalid input. Not an integer");
                }
                break;

                case 2:
                    System.out.println("Let's traverse the tree we just made!. ");
                    myCategoryChoice = KeyIn.inInt("Please select a traversal method: (1) Pre-Order (2) In-Order (3) Post-Order");

                    Boolean done = false;

                    do{
                        switch(myCategoryChoice){
                            case 1:
                                System.out.println("You've selected a pre-order traversal." + "\n");

                                context = new Context(preOrder);
                                context.traverse(myIntTree);

                                done = true;                        
                                break;

                            case 2:
                                System.out.println("You've selected an in-order traversal." + "\n");


                                context = new Context(inOrder);
                                context.traverse(myIntTree);

                                done = true;
                                break;

                            case 3:
                                System.out.println("You've selected a post-order traversal." + "\n");

                                context = new Context(postOrder);
                                context.traverse(myIntTree);

                                done = true;
                                break;
                        }
                    }while(!done);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("Goodbye!");
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Invalid selection.");
                    break;              
            }
        } while(inputOption != 3);
    }
}
```

Comment: What `BinaryTree` class are you using?

Comment: I created one..does that affect where I would be creating it though?

Answer (score 1):

Declare the variable without initializing it. And then create a new tree whenever the user enters `1`:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    //...
    BinaryTree myIntTree = null;

    inOrder = new InOrder();
    preOrder = new PreOrder();
    postOrder = new PostOrder();
    //...

    case 1:
        myIntTree = new BinaryTree();
    //...
    case 2:
        if(myIntTree == null) break;
    //...
}
```

Or since you created your own `BinaryTree` class, you can create a `clear()` method to remove each node from the tree and call that.

Comment: I tried your first suggestion but when I go that route, I get errors in the other switch statements stating that the variable was not initialized..I suppose I will write a clear method.  Thank you!

Comment: @calvarado: You can easily overcome that with a `continue` statement, after checking if the tree is `null`, of course you have to initialize to `null` when it is declared.

Comment: I'm sorry I've managed to get confused again...are you saying that I will be able to declare my tree inside of the 1st switch statement if I 'continue' instead of 'break' ?  I do initialize my tree to null when it is first created...

Comment: If I use 'continue switch' I get an error telling me to remove switch

Comment: @calvarado: Haha sorry, I don't use `continue` (or `switches`) that often. I will update my answer. Just use the `break` statement.

Comment: i don't understand how this solves my problem of not being able to refer to the tree from the other switch statements when the tree is created in the 1st switch statement?

Comment: @calvarado: That is the scope of the `BinaryTree` variable. Each case in the switch can access the `BinaryTree` object, because it is *declared* before it. The tree is *re-created* in the first switch statement.